# Chrome 62/63 MacOS performance issue with canvas and big image

Tags: google-chrome, html5-canvas

I'm facing a really weird issue on Chrome 62/63, only on MacOS (el capitan and sierra at least).

I have a big sprite (14400 * 4400), that is used inside a HTML5 canvas, and the animation that I do, is really really slow on this platform. I tried on Windows (this browser version and IE/Edge), no problem, and on a lot of other browser (opera neon, vivaldi, firefox, safari), there's no problem. Even on chrome 61 and before, there's no problem. It's only working when I activate the flag "Accelerated 2D canvas" on chrome 62+

I know, that the sprite is huge, its size is already divided by 2 (28800*8800 is the initial size), so is there any way to improve the performances via canvas config or something else ? (I already read [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Optimizing_canvas)), I almost follow everything from this article, except the "requestAnimationFrame", because I need to do the job at a certain time. (I don't know if it's a chrome bug or just me doing the wrong thing, but I have no more idea)